# How to add textual description to a resource in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I would like to add a textual description to each resource I've in my administrative portal. The main objective is describe to the final user what the resource will manage or change in the website.

**I want something like that:**

[image]

**Before you ask, in this case I've manually changed the HTML:**

[image]

I would like to know if there's an ActiveAdmin default feature that already do something like that. I've read the documentation and haven't found anything like that.

I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1, Ruby 2.3.0 and "ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2".

Comment: I've read the code that builds up the resource page, apparently there's no option to add page description.

Comment: That would be a nice feature request :/

Answer (score 0):

No, ActiveAdmin does not currently have that feature.  The way to implement would be to subclass ActiveAdmin::View::TitleBar and then register the subclass with ActiveAdmin::ViewFactory.  If you have it working for your own app feel free to submit it as a pull request.